# Armature animation and geometry nodes raycasting glitches?

Tags: armature, geometry-nodes

I have an armature (robotic paw) which have some wires in it. I wanted to animate the paw and use geometry nodes with raycasting to find out when the wire gets inside of the paw to move it to the surface. It works fine for me but from time to time there are some strange glitches.

The following to pictures show the problem.

This one looks ok:
[image]
This one looks bad:
[image]
This is the node setup for wires:
[image]

The base vertices of this wires, orange surface and the cylindrical thing are 100% weighted to the same bone. The main difference here is that this bone is positioned differently in space and relative to other bones. I have checked, however, there are no vertex groups from any other non-relevant bones in these wires.

Can you suggest what could be the problem? Raycasting precision?

UPD. Attached blend file [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

[image]

by this change you won't change the first vertices of your cable.

Comment: Heh. Thank you!